# Can you cover a sphere with (roughly) squares?

Tags: spheres, tiling

In the same way we have hexagons tiling the surface of a sphere, like with [Uber's H3](https://www.uber.com/blog/h3/), which has 12 pentagons at each of the icosahedron vertices, to make it work. What do you need to be able to recursively cover a sphere with squares (or rough squares, which might be stretched slightly to form parallelograms or otherwise)?

[image]

What is the system used to tile a sphere with squares basically? Ideally, when standing on a square, you see it as a square (if at all possible).

Comment: You mean something like [the Cube map projection](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/properties/cube.htm), but with many more than 6 squares?

Comment: You could use the surface of an nxnxn cube, projected out to a sphere, but then you will have 8 points where three "squares" meet so those squares are so distorted that they have one 120 degree corner. To avoid that you could start from a [chamfered cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chamfer_(geometry)). Truncate the 8 corners to form 8 triangles, the chamfered edges are split into a 1xn array of squares, the faces into nxn squares. When it is now projected out onto a sphere, the most distorted lattice points have 3 squares and one triangle meeting, which is not quite a bad.

Comment: Can you be specific about what "basically" permits? Uber has some pentagon faces; Jaap's suggestion involves some triangles. These exceptions are necessary: A sphere cannot be tiled by quadrilaterals with four meeting at a vertex because the Euler characteristic of such a tiling is $0$ ($E = 2F$, $V = F$) while the Euler characteristic of a sphere is $2$.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis can you expand that into an answer, that sounds pretty good.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang "Basically" permits anything that are ideally not curves, so straight lines only in an ideal world. So if you have to cut of the corner of squares to form other shapes, that stuff is fine to prevent distortion. If curves cannot be avoided, then minimizing the use of curves.